# What is "Third Generation Scale"?

Tags: metrics, lines-of-code

In the context of counting source lines of code (SLoC) what is the "Third Generation Scale" factor that is defined on each programming language?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out it might be a proprietary calculation made by [CLOC](http://cloc.sourceforge.net/).

*Source:* http://cloc.sourceforge.net/#scale_factors